# Prevent simultaneous deploys with Ansible

Tags: ansible

Anyone on my team can SSH into our special deploy server, and from there run an Ansible playbook to push new code to machines.

We're worried about what will happen if two people try to do deploys simultaneously. We'd like to make it so that the playbook will fail if anyone else is currently running it.

Any suggestions for how to do this? The standard solution is to use a pid file, but Ansible does not have built-in support for these.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could write a wrapper for ansible commands like so :

```
ansible-playbook() {
  lock="/tmp/ansible-playbook.lock"

  # Check if lock exists, return if yes
  if [ -e $lock ]; then
    echo "Sorry, someone is running already ansible from `cat $lock`"
    return
  fi

  # Install signal handlers
  trap "rm -f $lockfile; trap - INT TERM EXIT; return" INT TERM EXIT

  # Create lock file, saving originating IP
  echo $SSH_CLIENT | cut -f1 -d' ' > $lock

  # Run ansible with arguments passed at the command line
  `which ansible-playbook` "$@"

  # Remove lock file
  rm $lock

  # Remove signal handlers
  trap - INT TERM EXIT
}
```

Define this function in the `~/.bashrc` of your users on the deploy box and you're set.
You can do the same for the `ansible` command to if you wish, but given the question I'm not sure it's required.

EDIT: Rewrote with signal handler to prevent lock file dangling around if users hit Ctrl-C.

EDIT2: Fixed typo

Comment: Wow. This script is going to _mostly_ prevent two instances running, but not fully, due to the time gap between testing and creating the lock file. You need an atomic operation to have real protection, and though I am out of date with *nix, I think a script cannot do this. I presume RunDeck mentioned in next answer may have what's required, using IPC (semaphores, etc.).

Comment: In theory, yes, there is no 100%. You could lower the gap more doing something like `[ -e $lock ] || (echo $SSH_CLIENT | cut -f1 -d' ' > $lock)` (and adjust the script accordingly) which takes less than a millisecond. In practice, sounds quite reasonable. Or write the lock file with restricted perms so another user can not overwrite it. All in all of course, this is a hack at best. Rundeck looks cool.

Comment: flock with -c is an option here, like so `flock -x $HOME/.ansible_lock -c 'ansible-playbook ...'`

Answer (score 28):

Personally I use RunDeck ( http://rundeck.org/ ) as a wrapper around my Ansible playbooks for multiple reasons:

- You can set a RunDeck 'job' to only be able to be run at one time (or set it to run as many times at the same time as you want)
- You can set up users within the system so that auditing of who has run what is listed clearly
- You can set additional variables with constraints on what can be used (specify a list of options)
- Its a whole lot cheaper than Ansible Tower (RunDeck is free)
- It has a full API for running jobs pragmatically from build systems
- You don't need to write complicated bash wrappers around the ansible-playbook command
- SSH can become a litmus test of 'something needs an ansible script written' - I don't allow SSH access except in full on break/fix situations, and we have happier SA's as a result
- Lastly, and definitely way up there in the 'nice to have' category is you can schedule RunDeck jobs to run ansible playbooks in a very easy way for anybody who logs on to the console to see what is running when

There are many more good reasons of course, but my fingers are getting tired of typing  ;)

Comment: Are there any details online about how you have this set up?

Comment: @thisjustin Not fully as yet - I've been sidetracked by work lately, so my blog isn't quite at that point as yet - rundeck has the option to configure a job to only run if it isn't already running in its configuration per job and returns the appropriate 4XX code to say if a job is already running if that option is set (if you are using the API thats an important piece of info to know)

Comment: RunDeck looks like jenkins to me.

Answer (score 15):

I put this in my main playbook, after

```
    hosts: all.
```

`lock_file_path`: This is a file whose existence indicates that there is a currently running ansible deploy, or there was a deploy before, that got aborted for some reason.

`force_ignore_lock`: This defaults to false, reset by an option flag that you can set in a command-line wrapper to ansible. It enables ansible to continue with the deploy.

### What this does

#### `pre_tasks`

The first `pre_task` checks if the `lock_file_path` exists, and records the result in a register called `lock_file`.

The next task then checks to see if the file exists, and if the person deploying has chosen to ignore it (hopefully after communicating with other team-mates). If not, the job fails, with a helpful error message.

If the user chooses to move on with the deploy even if there was a `lock_file`, the next task deletes the previously created `lock_file` and creates a new one. The other tasks in the selected role then continue happily.

#### `post_tasks`

This is a hook called immediately after all the tasks in the deploy have been completed. The task here deletes the `lock_file`, enabling the next person to deploy happily, without any issues.

```
vars:
  lock_file_path=/tmp/ansible-playbook-{{ansible_ssh_user}}.lock

pre_tasks: 
   - stat: path={{lock_file_path}}
     register: lock_file

   - fail: msg="Sorry, I found a lockfile, so I'm assuming that someone was already running ansible when you started this deploy job. Add -f to your deploy command to forcefully continue deploying, if the previous deploy was aborted."
   when: lock_file.stat.exists|bool and not force_ignore_lock|bool

   - file: path={{lock_file_path}} state=absent
     sudo: yes
     when: "{{force_ignore_lock}}"

   - file: path={{lock_file_path}} state=touch
     sudo: yes

post_tasks:
   - file: path={{lock_file_path}} state=absent
     sudo: yes
```

Comment: If the ansible execution is interrupted you may end-up with a permanently locked machine. The existence of a lock file is not enough, it needs a way to detect if that's a stale lock or not.

Comment: This is why I added is: `when: lock_file.stat.exists|bool and not force_ignore_lock|bool`. This uses the `force_ignore_lock` variable that can be set in a command-line flag to a wrapper script written in e.g. python using click. Example: 

``

Comment: Example: 
    `@deploy.command()
     @click.option('--force',
                  help="Ignore the lock file that prevents parallel deploys, \
if a previous deploy was aborted.",
              is_flag=True,
              default=False)
    def backend(api_server, force):
    """Deploys the backend application."""

        if force:
            ignore_lock = 'true'
        else:
           ignore_lock = 'false'

        extra_vars = {
            'force_ignore_lock': ignore_lock
        }
        call_ansible(api_server, 'api_server.yml', json.dumps(extra_vars))`

Comment: this won't really work when 2 playbooks running simultaneously on the same host. It won't see the lock since you haven't create it yet. In most cases it won't really help.

Answer (score 11):

Have you considered setting `maxsyslogins` in limits.conf? You can restrict this by group.

```
# for a group called 'deployers'
@deployers        -       maxsyslogins      1
```

This is quite a bit more severe than what you asked for. You might want to try it on a VM first. Note that no-one from deployers will have access if there are any other users on the system at all, the 1 limit doesn't just count deployers. Also, if as a user you multiplex your ssh connections (ControlMaster auto), you will still be able to log in multiple times; it's other users who'd be locked out.

Comment: I had actually Googled for something to do exactly that as a possible solution, but couldn't find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can use the flock command, which will wrap your command with a filesystem-based flock(2):

```
$ flock /tmp/ansible-playbook.lock ansible-playbook foo bar baz
```

Wrap that however it suits your users best. This will leave a persistent lockfile in /tmp, but note that it is **not** safe to delete it[1]. It's atomic, and very simple.

```
[1]
A: flock /tmp/foo.lock -c "echo running; sleep 5; rm /tmp/foo.lock"
B: flock /tmp/foo.lock -c "echo running; sleep 5; rm /tmp/foo.lock"
   B blocks waiting for lock on /tmp/foo.lock
A: Finish, deleting /tmp/foo.lock
B: Runs, using lock on now deleted /tmp/foo.lock
C: flock /tmp/foo.lock -c "echo running; sleep 5; rm /tmp/foo.lock"
   Creates new /tmp/foo.lock, locks it and runs immediately, parallel with B
```

Answer (score 7):

Wrapper scripts aren't useful when deployment jobs could be run from multiple build hosts. For those kind of cases the locking has to be handled by the playbook.

Ansible now has a [wait_for](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/wait_for_module.html) module which can be used for locking. Here's a short example (with no consideration of stale locks):

```
vars:
  lock_file: "{{ deploy_dir }}/.lock"
pre_tasks:
  - name: check for lock file
    wait_for:
      path: "{{ lock_file }}"
      state: absent
  - name: create lock file
    file:
      path: "{{ lock_file }}"
      state: touch
post_tasks:
  - name: remove lock file
    file:
      path: "{{ lock_file }}"
      state: absent
```

Ansible will check for the lock file for a configurable timeout period, and then give up if it is not removed in that period.

Comment: Everything that is not using the file lock kernel feature is a non working hack. Flock exists in Unix for 40 years and ansible still can’t use it out of the box 6 years after. What a shame

Answer (score 0):

You can also use simple variant of wrapper:

```
# Check lock file - if exists then exit. Prevent running multiple ansible instances in parallel
while kill -0 $(cat /tmp/ansible_run.lock 2> /dev/null) &> /dev/null; do
  echo "Ansible is already running. Please wait or kill running instance."
  sleep 3
done
# Create lock file
echo $$ > /tmp/ansible_run.lock

ansible-playbook main.yml

# Remove lock
rm -f /tmp/ansible_run.lock
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into a distributed lock mechanism like zookeeper that I would include as a role, as there is a [`znode`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/znode_module.html) module. Distributed for high-availability and writing lock out of the target nodes.

The role would write a znode of the target name under `/deployment/` at the beginning and would delete it after. If the lock already exists you can fail and throw a message in a `block`.